# Access to energy history of Nest Thermometer via SDM API

Tags: nest-device-access, google-sdm-api

Is there a way to retrieve energy history usage from device using SDM API ?
It seems there is only 10 days of data on the device, so I would like a way to periodically update my local data historian, but I cant seem to find API call. Only things I can see are related to get/set realtime values.

Answer (score 0):

Currently we don't have any APIs supporting the retrieval of energy history usage from device using SDM API. I would recommend opening up a feature request in this regard on the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/). This will help us in putting it on the road map for future developments.